# TFS workitem field cannot be validated in Eval

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, tfs, wiql

I have a TFS work item field that seems to exist for most work items, but sometimes doesn't.

I'm attempting to bind these workitems in a listview using a WorkItemCollection, and everything works except when I attempt binding that field.

The field itself is specified in the query select and gives no error. However the only way to get the field without throwing an error on some workitems is as so (in the .cs)::

```
          foreach(WorkItem w in queryResults)
          {
            if (w.Fields.Contains("Symptom"))
            {
              w.Fields["Symptom"].Value.ToString();//show
            }
          }
```

as these workitems are in readonly mode, I can't just force write the value etc.. (unless I return a Dictionnary with the value paired with the workitem, but I don't think that would be the best solution...)

What I'm attempting to do is in the Listview ItemTemplate, something like this::

```
                <div class="details">
                    <%# Server.HtmlEncode(Eval("Fields.Contains(\"Symptom\")? Fields[\"Symptom\"].Value : \"\";").ToString())%>
                </div>
```

But I get the 'Contains' is not a valid 'Fields' property (because its a collection method) - I'm stuck with the eval

How can I properly evaluate and display my Symptom field?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Do you use CMMI process template? I've checked my TFS 2015.3, only Bug work item contains Symptom field in CMMI process template. Do you mean you want to get this field with TFS api?

Comment: Can you share your code which can not work?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT , that is exactly the problem, for any workitem that isn't a 'bug' workitem, there's no symptom field - so I can't bind that field directly , it will throw an error. I need to bind it WHEN it's there, but I'm having a hard time doing that in the html page

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT , umm that's exactly what I posted. Through the code (.cs / pagebehind), I can get the field fine as is shown in the first codeblock, in the page, I cannot eval if the field is there or not - it throws an error - > see second codeblock

Answer (score 0):

If you use TFS 2015 or VSTS, you can use [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#with-specific-fields) to get Symptom field. The API look like:

```
GET http(s)://{instance}/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=xx&fields=Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.Symptom&api-version=1.0
```

Or with .net Api:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using System;

namespace TestCaseProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tfs =
         TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(
             new Uri("http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/CollectionName"));
            var service = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

            var wi = service.GetWorkItem(id);


            foreach (Field field in wi.Fields)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", field.Name, field.Value);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The .net API section is exactly what I already stated works (first codeblock in my post) - the issue is binding the workitemcollection to a listview and using the symptom field (which doesn't always exist).

Answer (score 0):

**Use OnItemDataBound**

Nothing seemed to work directly on the page so I moved away from that approach and went with attempting to solve my problem in the codebehind, since I was already capable of sorting it out on that front.

I removed my sourceObject from my page and instead had the codebehind programmatically databind my listview. (this step is not necessary)

```
TFSListView.DataSource = SearchHandler.SearchTFS(searchstring);
TFSListView.DataBind();
```

Then I used OnItemDatabound event to be able to manage each item being bound, I check if that annoying symptom field exist for the dataitem being bound and fill up the appropriate control if it does (all this replaces one eval line, so I'm still a bit annoyed but it didn't seem to be possible directly in the aspx page)

```
protected void TFSListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
  ListViewDataItem myitem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item; 

  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem) 
  {
    Control divDetails = e.Item.FindControl("divLsvDetails");
    WorkItem myWI = myitem.DataItem as WorkItem;

    if (myWI != null && divDetails != null)
    {          
      if (myWI.Fields.Contains("Symptom"))
      {            
        ((HtmlGenericControl)divDetails).InnerHtml = myWI["Symptom"].ToString();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I won't accept this as an answer (also because I asked the question) because it doesn't answer the question directly - how to get it to work directly in the aspx.page , using eval or w/e. I posted it in case others get the same problem though, as it does solve it.